# How to pass multiple parameters to stored procedure using pdo in php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I've a procedure which takes multiple params as input and gives output to one variable

here i'm pasting my code below.

**Updated**

```
$sqlStr = 'call sp_testproc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
$stmt = $c->prepare($sqlStr);

$bindValues = array(
    'fields' => array(
       array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':From', 'value' => 'adsfad@adsf.com', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':To', 'value' => 'anil.g@adf.com', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':Cc', 'value' => '', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':Bcc', 'value' => '', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':Subject', 'value' => 'some value given', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':someId', 'value' => 10334, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INT),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':someId1', 'value' => 307560, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INT),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':ReadOrUnread', 'value' => 1, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INT),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':HasAttachments', 'value' => 1, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INT),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':someId2', 'value' => 9, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INT),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':someId3', 'value' => 89, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INT),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':link', 'value' => 'http:google.com', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':someId4', 'value' => 3998, 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'input', 'name' => ':MailDate', 'value' => '2014-02-01', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_STR),
        array('type' => 'output', 'value' => '$Id', 'data_type' => PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT),
    )
);

$proc_pass_val = null;
if (isset($bindValues['fields']) && is_array($bindValues['fields'])) {
    $arg_cnt = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($bindValues['fields']); $i++) {
        $bindValue = $bindValues['fields'][$i]["value"];
        $param_type = $bindValues['fields'][$i]["type"];
        $data_type = $bindValues['fields'][$i]["data_type"];

        if ($param_type == 'input') {
            $stmt->bindValue($arg_cnt++, $bindValue, $data_type);
        } elseif ($param_type == 'output') {
            $stmt->bindParam($arg_cnt++, $proc_pass_val, $data_type);
        }
    }
}


$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $proc_pass_val\n";
```

**Note:** I'm using MSSQL server

I want the Procedure output in $Id variable, please suggest me where i went wrong

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `... using question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter...` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) `$arg_cnt` not initialized so put `$arg_cnt=1` before loop or use `++$arg_cnt`

Comment: bindParam second arg shoud be `$$bindValue` i think

Comment: I want the variable to be in `$Id ` so i pass like that, if i pass string literal i think it'll raise an error that can't pass param 2 by reference

Comment: Why you're using an array and a loop? Why can't you just write your binding one by one?

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is a single call not multiple inserts loop is for parameter binding overcomplicated

Comment: `print "procedure returned $bindValue\n";` your binding output here

Comment: @cske you're fast :) yeah I got it the moment I posted. It makes this question even stranger. why all this array hassle at all then?

Comment: FYI, I've changed binding param to `$proc_pass_val`, but no use and i'm accessing that, but no use @cske  and   @YourCommonSense

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just passed the parameter length to **bindParam** like this

```
$stmt->bindParam($arg_cnt++, $proc_pass_val, $data_type, [Length of the data type])
```

and it worked for me

the code is more readable in this [solution](http://trentrichardson.com/2011/08/10/making-sense-of-stored-procedures-with-php-pdo-and-sqlsrv/)